# Qml StackView Push Transition is not working

Tags: qt, qml

I'm making an application with Qt and QML `( version 5.10 )` and using `Qt.QuickControl 1.5`.

I'm facing a problem with the StackView Transition: 
Whenever I push an Item I make a simple Sliding Transition, the `enterItem` slides in and the `exitItem` slides out.

```
   StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        delegate: StackViewDelegate {
            pushTransition: StackViewTransition {
                PropertyAnimation {
                    target: exitItem
                    property: "x"
                    from: 0
                    to: exitItem.width
                }

                PropertyAnimation {
                    target: enterItem
                    property: "x"
                    from: -enterItem.width
                    to: 0
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

It's really simple. The problem is that when I push an Object in the StackView the transition is not happening. BUT when I pop the Transition I see the transition.

I create the objects for the StackView dynamically like
`stackView.push(Qt.createComponent(_someurl_).createObject());`

I cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: Any reasons why you are not using Qt Quick Controls 2?

Comment: Did you try just to give `someurl_` to push() instead of creating the component yourself? I believe `StackView` will handle that as well

Comment: @GrecKo For some requirements I have to follow. I've tried also with just URL but it's not working either.